# Managing PerformancePoint Filters With Slowly Changing Dimensions

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, performancepoint, scd, scd2

Just a bit of background info:

I have dimension table which uses SCD2 to track user changes in our company (team changes, job title changes etc) See example below:

[image: Some of the User dimension columns]

I've built an Analysis Services Cube and created all the necessary hierarchy's for the dimensions and it works well when navigating and drilling down through the fact table.

[image: SSAS Hierarchy]

The problem I have is with the filters on the PerformancePoint dashboard. As I'm using the User Dimension table with it's multiple instances of users it's showing duplicates up in the list. I can understand why as the surrogate ID is being referenced on the Dimension. But if I choose the first instance of the A-team I will see all their sales for a particular period and if I choose the second instance I will see all their sales for a different period.

[image: Example of 1 of the duplicated team names]

What is the best way to handle this type of behavior? Ideally I'd like to see a distinct list of teams in alphabetical order and when I choose the team name it shows all of their data over time.

I've considered using MDX query filters but I'd like to see if there's anything I haven't thought about.

I realise this isn't an easy and quick question but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple after having a trawl through my User Dimension table on the Cube.

1. Under my user dimension I added 2 duplicate attributes to my attributes list ("Team Filter" is a copy of "Team", "User Filter" a copy of "User Name") these will be used only for filtering the dashboard.

[image: Dimension Designer Window]

2. Under the attribute properties for each duplicate I then set AttributeHierarchyOptimizedState to "Not Optimized", I also set their AttributeHierarchyVisible to false as I'd shown the two duplicate attributes in the hierarchy window in the middle.

[image: Dimension Attribute Properties]

3. Deploy your Cube to the server and go in to PerformancePoint. Create a new MDX Filter (this image shows the finished filter)

[image: Create a MDX Filter in PerformancePoint]

4. This is the code I used, it only shows dimension members which have a fact against them (reduces the list a considerable amount) and by using allmembers at the dimension it also gives me the option to show "All" at the top of the list.

[image: MDX Code]

5. Deploy the new filters and now you can see the distinct list of users and teams, works perfectly and selects every instance (regardless of the SCD2 row)

[image: Dashboard Filters now working]